# Dynamically filter ng-repeat according to input click event

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am building an app that have a sidebar with an input range [like 100m,200m...]

Then I have my main content body with articles (stored in angular array).

I want to filter articles (by distance) with the input range.

How can I do that ?

For the moment I tried to parse ng-model INSIDE ng-repeat's filter but doesn't work (yes i'm a noob...).

See the app here : http://nicolaslarzilliere.fr/dev/

Thanks in advance.

[Sorry for the language, I'm french]

```js
$(window).load(function(){
 
 var clickOrTouch = (('ontouchend' in window)) ? 'touchend' : 'click';
 
 $('#menu').on(clickOrTouch, function() {
  $('#sidebar').toggleClass('open_sidebar');
  $('#page').toggleClass('move_page');
 });
 
 $('section').hammer().on('tap', function() {
  $('section .description').not($(this).find('.description')).animate({
   'height' : '0px'
  }, 200);
  $('.arrow').not($(this).find('.arrow')).removeClass('rotate');
  $(this).find('.description').animate({
   'height' : '115px'
  }, 200);
  $(this).find('.arrow').addClass('rotate');
 });
 
});

var app = angular.module("Resto",[]);

 
app.controller('Restaurants', function($scope){
 
 var val = $('input[type=range]').val();
 $scope.greaterThan = function(prop, val){
  
  console.log($('input[type=range]').val());
     return function(item){
      if (item[prop] >= val) return true;
     }
 }
 
 $scope.etablissement = [ 
  {
   name: 'Pub Le Galway',
   distance: '800',
   plat: 'Tenneessee Rosti burger',
  },
  {
   name: 'Pub Le Galway',
   distance: '500',
   plat: 'Poulet rôti',
  },
  {
   name: '',
   distance: '200',
   plat: 'Coquilles Saint Jacques',
  },
  {
   name: 'Pub Le Galway',
   distance: '100',
   plat: 'Foie Gras Poêlé',
  },
 ]; 
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="Resto">
 <header class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
   <span class="ion-navicon" id="menu"></span>
  </div>
 </header>
 <div id="sidebar" class="col-xs-9" ng-controller="Restaurants">
  <input type="range" min="100" ng-change="greaterThan()" step="100" max="1000" value="{{value}}" ng-model="value" />
  <span>{{value}}</span>
 </div>
 <div id="page" class="row" ng-controller="Restaurants">
  <section class="row min" ng-repeat="restaurant in etablissement | filter: greaterThan('distance', '') | orderBy: 'distance'">
   <div class="col-xs-9 ion-arrow-down-b arrow">
    <h1>{{restaurant.plat}}</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
    <h2 class="ion-ios-location">{{restaurant.distance}} m</h2></span>
   </div>
   <div class="row description">
    <hr>
   </div>
  </section>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you post some code?  And have you looked at `ng-change` as a possible solution?

Comment: Could you post some code of what you tried?

Comment: You could maybe try something like filter: greaterThan('distance', 'value'), where value is the model of the slider, it has to be an interger though. Also it's worth mentioning, mixing angular and jquery isn't the best, if you use angular it's better to avoid direct dom manipuation like jquery if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Set a model on the input, and then use that model to filter the repeat as results.

```
<input name="someinputnumber" ng-nodel="numberFilterValue" />
<div ng-repeat="thing in list | filter: greaterThan(thing.distance, numberFilterValue)">
  {{thing.name}}
</div>

//OR

<div ng-repeat="thing in list" ng-show="greaterThan(thing.distance, numberFilterValue)">
  {{thing.name}}
</div>
```